# Component cannot be used as a JSX component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React component like this

```js
import React from 'react';
import { ECOTileSummary } from './ECOTileSummary';
import { TileSummary } from './TileSummary';

interface SuperTileSummaryProps {
  date?: string;
  location: string;
  link: string;
  title: string;
  nextVisit?: string | null;
  tileEntity?: string;
}

export const SuperTileSummary = ({
  date,
  location,
  link,
  title,
  nextVisit,
  tileEntity,
}: SuperTileSummaryProps) => {
  const chooseRegularTileByEntity = () => {
    switch (tileEntity && tileEntity) {
      case 'EmailCampaign':
        return <ECOTileSummary date={date} link={link} location={location} title={title} />;
      default:
        return (
          <TileSummary
            nextVisit={nextVisit}
            date={date}
            link={link}
            location={location}
            title={title}
          />
        );
    }
  };
  
  return chooseRegularTileByEntity;
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

and I am calling it inside another component like this

```
import { SuperTileSummary} from './SuperTileSummary'

export const Wrapper = () => {
   return(
       <div>
          <SuperTileSummary 
             nextVisit={nextVisit}
             date={date}
             link={link}
             location={location}
             title={title}
             tileEntity={tileEntity}
           />
       </div>
   );
 };
```

and I am getting an error like this: 'SuperTileSummary' cannot be used as a JSX component.
Its return type '() => JSX.Element' is not a valid JSX element.
Type '() => Element' is missing the following properties from type 'Element': type, props, keyts(2786)'.
I am not sure what am I doing wrong here since I'm rendering the component.

Comment: Have you tried `return chooseRegularTileByEntity();` ?

Comment: @Milos isn't it simply that `SuperTileSummary` is not imported?

Comment: I think the problem is that he's returning a function that returns JSX, rather than returning JSX. that's what the error message says

Comment: What is your question? The error message tells you exactly what is wrong.

Comment: @Hiro I made a mistake in the rush, I have edited the code now.

Comment: @HåkenLid but I'm not sure what is wrong and how to fix this

Comment: @TKoL I have tried this, but now getting this kind of error: `Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.`

Comment: @Milos this happens a lot in stackoverflow. "but then this error occurs" is another question. And the answer to this original question is definitely TKoL's.

Comment: That might be a problem with your other components. In your `switch` section, try just changing both to a normal `<p>text</p>` and see if that works. If the p tags work, then it's a problem with those other components

Comment: Have you tried wrapping ECOTileSummary in ()?

Comment: @HåkenLid raises a good question down there. Why do you even have that switch statement like that in a function? why not just write switch statement directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `chooseRegularTileByEntity` function to get the returned value:

```
return chooseRegularTileByEntity();
```

or use it as component:

```
const ChooseRegularTileByEntity = () => {
    //...
};

return <ChooseRegularTileByEntity />
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message, `'SuperTileSummary' cannot be used as a JSX component. Its return type '() => JSX.Element' is not a valid JSX element.`, suggests that you're giving back a function that returns a JSX element where it expects a JSX element itself.

I believe the fix is to change `return chooseRegularTileByEntity;` to `return chooseRegularTileByEntity();` The former is the function that returns JSX, the latter is the returned JSX itself

Comment: What is the purpose of the function `chooseRegularTileByEntity`?

Comment: @HåkenLid it's returning the component based on props

Comment: Why do it so complicated? It seems this could be a single line instead. `const SuperTileSummary = props => props.tileEntity === 'EmailCampaign' ? <ECOTileSummary {...props} /> : <TileSummary {...props} />`. How did you come up with  `switch (tileEntity && tileEntity)`? What is the reason for using `&&` here?

Comment: Because I plan to have more components in this switch, not only these two